# How to use Apple TV Remote in landscape?

Tags: device-orientation, tvos

Is there a tvOS API to detect landscape orientation and/or allow use of the Apple TV controller for touch gesture input with the controller held in landscape?  (e.g. so the app will get a swipe up event with respect to the floor/gravity whether the controller is portrait or turned sideways).

Answer (score 1):

I've played a little bit around with the AppleTV and the remote. Gesture recognition on the remote is possible. I've copied the sample code from my [Blog article](http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.de/2015/09/quick-tip-how-to-use-remote-control-in.html#more) about this.

For detecting the orientation of the remote [this answer from the Apple Developer forum might be helpful.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18861)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    /* Setup your scene here */

    // Add Sprite
    sprite.xScale = 0.5
    sprite.yScale = 0.5
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(sprite)

    // Register Swipe Events
    let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


    let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)


    let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp:"))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)


    let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

}

// Handle Swipe Events
func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x + 10, y: sprite.position.y)
}

func swipedLeft(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x - 10, y: sprite.position.y)
}

func swipedUp(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x, y: sprite.position.y+10)
}

func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x, y: sprite.position.y-10)
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

}